# Which Red5 version am i running?

Tags: linux, centos, version, red5

I was wandering, sounds easy but I couldn't find out. How can I find out which [Red5](http://www.red5.org/) version am I using?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments [here](http://avchathq.com/blog/how-do-i-know-what-red5-version-i-am-running/):

```
cat /var/log/boot.log | grep “Red5 Server”
```